# How to replicate using joins and unions?

Tags: tableau-api

I have an SQL script I want to replicate inside tableau using tableau's joins.

SQL script (script simplified just for explanation):

```sql
Select *
From transactions 
Inner join data1

UNION 

Select *
From transactions
Inner join data2
```

How do replicate this in tableau using joins n unions? (No tableau custom SQL please)

Answer (score 1):

You can do manual unions or wildcard unions: [Tableau Help](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-gb/union.htm)
Depending on your data connection, some features of it may or may not be supported.

Same with joins, lots of ways to do it: [Tableau Help](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-gb/joining_tables.htm)

Make sure you're looking up the docs and searching for an answer before posting. These types of this are easy to find.